# Why does `systemctl show -p ActiveState $some_service` give a permission denied error for only some users?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, systemd

I've got a service that's running fine called "core" that has the following service file:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/core.service
[Unit]
Description=ExampleCo Core Service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/example/backend/bin/python3 /home/example/core/core.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/example/core
User=example
Group=example

Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service runs perfectly.

I've written a service-status script that runs the following command:

```
systemctl show -p ActiveState core
```

This command runs perfectly when called by `example`, `root` and `user1`, but when `user2` runs it, they get this error:

```
Failed to get properties: Access denied
```

If user2 calls it with `sudo`, then it works.

Running `strace -e trace=connect,sendmsg,recvmsg systemctl show -p ActiveState core` shows it's talking to `/run/dbus/system_bus_socket`, sending `AUTH EXTERNAL 12345\r\nNEGOTIATE_UNIX_FD\r\nBEGIN\r\n`, and receiving `REJECTED EXTERNAL\r\nERROR "Need to authenticate first"\r\n`.

Running `fuser /run/dbus/system_bus_socket` shows two processes listening: systemd (pid=1) and dbus-daemon (pid=474).  Running `strace -p 474` shows that dbus-daemon is getting the message, opening and reading the passwd file, and rejecting the request without logging anything.

Question: How do I fix this so that user2 can call it?

Meta-questions:

- Where does systemd log these failures?

  - While running the command once a second, I looked for log files on the system that were less than a minute old, and found no mention of the service or the user.
- How does systemd decide who can run commands?

  - We're using IPA/sssd/IDM, if that makes a difference.

Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04
Systemd version: systemd-237-3ubuntu10.52.deb

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer became obvious once I compared the strace outputs between user1 and user2: dbus-daemon doesn't know about any user that's not in /etc/passwd and will reject their requests with a "Need to authenticate first" error (which is mangled into "Permission denied" by the systemctl command).

And user1 is in /etc/passwd while user2 is an IDM user (LDAP, no entry in /etc/passwd).

Doing `getent passwd user2 >> /etc/passwd` was enough to enable their access.  Now I just have to figure out how to do it correctly.  :-/